# BASH how to filenames from a file and zcat them

Tags: bash, xargs, zcat

Suppose I have a directory with contents like this:

```
$ ls
file1.csv.gz
file2.csv.gz
file3.csv.gz
file4.csv.gz
listOfFiles.txt
```

`listOfFiles.txt` contains a list of the files which I want to zcat and pipe to awk to process their contents.  For instance, `listOfFiles.txt` might contain the following:

```
$ cat listOfFiles.txt
file2.csv.gz
file3.csv.gz
```

In this case, I would want `zcat` to operate on file2.csv.gz and file3.csv.gz, and not on any of the other files in the directory.  One way to do this is (EDIT: removed `{}` from `xargs zcat {}` based on comments):

```
cat listOfFiles.txt | xargs zcat | awk ...
```

But I am wondering if there is a more succinct way that `zcat` can read the names of the files from `listOfFiles.txt`.  It would have to be able to handle an arbitrarily long list of filenames, which `xargs` handles fine, and ideally it would invoke `zcat` only once for the entire contents of `listOfFiles.txt`, and not once per file contained in `listOfFiles.txt`.

Comment: Since you say the list can be arbitrarily long, I don't see a better solution than `xargs` to minimize the number of calls to `zcat`.

Comment: To be clear, `xargs` already does, by default, try to coalesce arguments into as few command invocations as possible, so it'll run `zcat file2.csv.gz file3.csv.gz` -- not `zcat file2.csv.gz` followed by `zcat file3.csv.gz` -- if called with defaults intact (no `-I`, `-J`, `-n`, etc). `{}` only makes sense with `-I {}` preceding it, but best practice is not to use that option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid `cat`:

```
xargs zcat < listOfFiles.txt | awk ...
```

Comment: The `-I` form is less efficient, since it implies `-n 1`. Is there any reason to use it here?

Comment: (Also, the OP explicitly wants to invoke `zcat` as few times as possible, a purpose which leaving out `-I` helps to serve).

Comment: But you're right, why should an answer show inefficient options